# Configure find not to even look in directories, if directory name maches 2012

Tags: linux, path, find

I'm using `find /home/myid/dir-with100directories/ -mmin -5 -not -path "*/2012/*` to find all files, except not in directory 2012, but somehow it works really really slow.

And my guess is that find looks in ALL directories, just does not show/hide results for 2012? Am I correct or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude a path you need to make it match properly in the `-path` option. The option requires you to write a fully matching path, including the absolute path prefix, so just `/2012/` is not enough.

```
find /home/myid/dir-with100directories/ -mmin -5 \
-not -path '/home/myid/dir-with100directories/2012/*'
```

Or:

```
cd /home/myid/dir-with100directories/
find . -mmin -5 -not -path './2012/*'
```

If you want to exclude any folder with the name `2012` in it – with GNU `find`:

```
cd /home/myid/dir-with100directories/
find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '.*/2012\(/.*\)?'
```

Or, to prune directories with the name `2012`:

```
cd /home/myid/dir-with100directories/
find . -type d -and -name '2012' -prune -o -print
```

The above will print everything else as an action (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896564/what-does-prune-option-in-find-do) for more info).

---

If you use Bash, you can skip a `2012` directory right away:

```
shopt -s extlob
find /home/myid/dir-with100directories/!(2012) -mmin -5
```

The same idea with Zsh:

```
setopt extendedglob
find /home/myid/dir-with100directories/^2012 -mmin -5
```

Comment: I have more than 200 directories. for example:<br> /home/myid/dir-with100directories/a1/2012 <br>/home/myid/dir-with100directories/aaabbb222/2012 <br>and so on.

Comment: Then you can use a path option like `-path '*/2012*'` – but this would also exclude files starting with `2012`. Or `find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '.*/2012\(/.*\)?'`.

Comment: somehow does not work any of suggestions. All are 1 minute and 20 seconds, however if rightly excluded search should look in folders, where are one or more files (in 2012 are hundreds /tens of files in every directory). If excluded correctly should execute in less than 20 seconds.

Comment: find /home/myid/dir-with100directories/ -mmin -5 -not -path '/home/myid/dir-with100directories/*/2012/'
I tried this, but also no luck!

Comment: If you end the `-path` with a slash it will not exclude all that is below the directory – just the directory itself. Try the `prune` option I added to my answer.

Comment: still can not get working

Comment: Please show a small self-contained example in your question so we can troubleshoot this better. Initially I thought there was only one directory to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

See the option `-prune` in the man page of find, and an example given in the description of the option `-path`.